# Is there a faster way to select records from a table and query its sub tables

Tags: mysql

He everyone,

I would like to get all records from a table that are changed, but also if one of its child tables has changed.

I have a working query that does this using subqueries but it takes very long (2 minutes) to complete.

Is there any other way to accomplish this that runs faster?

Thanks!
Wouter

```
SELECT
    wp_posts.id AS order_id,
    br_order_archive.id AS archive_id,
    wp_posts.post_date_gmt AS date,
    wp_posts.post_modified_gmt AS lastmod
FROM
    wp_posts
LEFT JOIN 
    br_order_archive ON br_order_archive.order_id = wp_posts.id 
WHERE
    wp_posts.post_type = "shop_order"
AND
    wp_posts.post_status = "wc-completed"
AND (
    br_order_archive.order_id IS NULL 
    OR wp_posts.post_modified_gmt != br_order_archive.lastmod
    OR br_order_archive.lastmod_licenses != (
        select max(wp_woocommerce_software_licenses.created)
        from wp_woocommerce_software_licenses
        where wp_posts.id = wp_woocommerce_software_licenses.order_id
        )
    OR br_order_archive.lastmod_activations != (
        select max(wp_woocommerce_software_activations.activation_time)
        from wp_woocommerce_software_activations
        LEFT JOIN wp_woocommerce_software_licenses ON wp_woocommerce_software_activations.key_id = wp_woocommerce_software_licenses.key_id 
        where wp_posts.id = wp_woocommerce_software_licenses.order_id
        )
    )
ORDER BY 
    wp_posts.ID desc
```

Comment: As well as SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for all relevant tables, questions about query performance always require the EXPLAIN for the given query

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of the necessary debugging information, let's start with this bit....

```
select max(a.activation_time)
  from wp_woocommerce_software_activations a
  LEFT 
  JOIN wp_woocommerce_software_licenses l
    ON a.key_id = l.key_id
  where p.id = l.order_id
```

A LEFT JOIN on a table from which you select no columns is a strange thing, as is the correlation between the LEFT JOINed table and the posts table (p). Normally, a LEFT JOINed table would not have an equals operator in a WHERE clause. For my own sanity, I would start by rewriting this as an uncorrelated subquery, regardless of the impact on performance.